# Generic type hint python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, type-hinting, python-typing

I have following code in python. Is it possible to get here intellisense in Visual Studio Code?

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

# Example class for a possible type T
class MyT:
    def name():
        return "I'm T"

class FooBar:
    def __init__(self, something: T) -> None:
        self.its_t = something

foo_bar = FooBar(MyT())
intellisense_test = foo_bar.its_t
```

Visual Studio Code says

[image]

so does not recognize the type and has no intellisense and no suggestion for "name"

Comment: Is it a typo? The class is `MyT` but you declared an (unrelated) TypeVar for `T` (without *My*)...

Comment: No, you can pass in any type. And this type is written to `self.its_t`. And depending on the type there should be intellisense. It works fine when you return that type in the same function the parameter comes in, but not as class field

Comment: What happens when `FooBar` inherits from `typing.Generic[T]`?

Comment: it's working!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to declare the `FooBar` class as `Generic` w.r.t. `T`

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class FooBar(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, something: T) -> None:
        self.its_t = something
```